# jQuery: Mixing Strings and List of Javascript Objects in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, controller

What I'm trying to do is possibly quite simple, however beeing not very familiar with jQuery I can't figure out how to do it.

I want to send some Data as JSON to an ASP.NET Controller. The Data contains some Strings and a list of Objects.

The Code would look somewhat like this:

View:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var stuff = [
        { id: 1, option: 'someOption' },
        { id: 2, option: 'someOther' },
        { id: 3, option: 'anotherOne' }
    ];

    things = JSON.stringify({ 'things': things });
    var dataRow = {
        'String1': 'A String',
        'String2': 'AnotherOne'
    }
    dataRow = JSON.stringify(dataRow);
    var sendData = dataRow + things;
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Backend/DoStuffWithStuff',
        data: sendData,
        success: function () {
            alert('Success!');
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('Fail! :(');
        }
    });
});
```

Controller:

```
    public class Stuff
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string option{ get; set; }
    }

    public void DoStuffWithStuff(string String1, String2, List<Thing> things)
    {
        //Do my Stuff
    }
```

Any Ideas would be great! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually doesn't look too bad so far! Just a few things...

```
[HttpPost]
public void DoStuffWithStuff(string String1, String2, List<Stuff> things)
{
    //Do my Stuff
}
```

In here, you don't actually give a type to string2. I'm going to assume this is a typo, but that's the minor part here.

Also, in that method, notice it has the HttpPost on the top. In your javascript here:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    type: 'POST',
    ...
});
```

You specify POST, so you must make the method support post (You could also get away with GET in this case by changing type to GET, then removing the attribute, but i'm not sure what your "stuff" entails...)

```
var stuff = [
    { id: 1, option: 'someOption' },
    { id: 2, option: 'someOther' },
    { id: 3, option: 'anotherOne' }
];

things = JSON.stringify({ 'things': things });
var dataRow = {
    'String1': 'A String',
    'String2': 'AnotherOne'
}
dataRow = JSON.stringify(dataRow);
var sendData = dataRow + things;
```

You didn't actually pass stuff into your method, which may be helpful...

Here is the ajax method re-written with the proper JSON pass (for what you're trying to do here).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stuff = [
        { id: 1, option: 'someOption' },
        { id: 2, option: 'someOther' },
        { id: 3, option: 'anotherOne' }
    ];
    var dataRow = {
        String1: 'A String',
        String2: 'AnotherOne'
        things: stuff
    }
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Backend/DoStuffWithStuff',
        data: sendData,
        success: function () {
            alert('Success!');
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('Fail! :(');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to modify a few things, but now it works like a charm. I had to remove the contentType value as it breaks everything for some reason and I needed to remove the JSON.stringify inside my dataRow. Now everything works just fine!

Comment: Not a problem! Thanks for the note, I will update my answer for others

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to stringify the json data.
You just create an object you van to send and than

```
var jsonObject = {
   'string' : 'string',
   'object' : {
       'stirng': 'string'
   }
};

$.ajax({type: "POST", url: DotNetScript, data: jsonObject})
.done(function(dataBack){
   //what to do with data back
});
```